# Create a vector of unique items in one column according to a date in another column

Tags: r, unique, lapply

I'm trying to create a vector using `c()`. 
I have a column of CIK numbers that I want to put into that vector by a year variable column.

```
df --> my dataframe name 

df$CIK --> CIK column of my dataframe

df$year--> year column of my dataframe # (ranges from 1994-2015)
```

So ultimately I would want this

```
CIK1994 <- vector of unique CIKs in 1994 

CIK1995 <- vector of unique CIKs in 1995 

.....

CIK2015 <- vector of unique CIKs in 2015
```

Is there an efficient way I can create those vectors using a for-loop / `lapply`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: At the very least, provide the output of `head(df)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a loop:

```
set.seed(4444)
df <- round(data.frame(CIK=runif(50,10000,99999),year=runif(50,1994,2015)),0)

for(i in unique(df$year)) assign(paste0("CIK",i),unique(df$CIK[df$year==i]))
```

Comment: Great! Feel free to mark this as the answer if you are satisfied with it.